# 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-403

I have this [page](http://myposnation.com/index1.php)  and if you view the net tab in firebug you will see a 403 forbidden error on the images folder but I can see the image when I view it in firebug... Any ideas what maybe causing the issue? There is no htaccess in this directory... There is one in the folder above it but there is nothing that I see that stands out to be blocking that folder... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by apache configuration somehow, try putting .htaccess file containing:

```
<Directory path/to/dir>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Directory>
```

And see what happens.

Comment: i added this <Directory img/>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Directory> and now  have this Internal Server Error

Comment: this needs to be absolute patch, like `/var/www/site123/img/` and try putting it into quotes.